# Multiple routers for an Ember app

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-router

Is it possible to have multiple router.js for an Ember app?

By default one router.js will have

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from '../../config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

export default Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('sampleroute');

});
```

and other router.js will have

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from '../../config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

export default Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('sampleroute2');

});
```

All I need is to make Ember application to read my second router(router2.js) which by default reads the default router.js to set up routes.

Comment: Why do u need to do this? whats ur usecase?

Comment: I want two routers.js for a single app. 2nd one come into the app based on requirements.

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1847

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define ur routes in seprate files inside a function and export that function like

page1.js

```
export default function() {
  this.route('page1');
}
```

page2.js

```
export default function() {
  this.route('page2');
}
```

Then import that into your router.js file.

```
import page1Routes from 'page1';
import page2Routes from 'page2';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  page1Routes.call(this);
  page2Routes.call(this);       
});

export default Router;
```

You can call Router.map repeatedly to add new routes. So you can import ur other routes the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate your functions as blessenm shown [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30454985/4545506).
But in that case you are continuing to keep a dependency to those files. And router.js is continuing to be a resource used by nearly all developers.

In addition to that answer:
For each modul, you can generate a "modul-route.js" file exporting that function. Then by using instance-initializers, you can collect all this functions and run *Router.map(...);* function for all loaded files.